# Terminal 'command_not_found' error

Tags: ruby, shell

When I navigate to a terminal and try to input a command such as `puts 1+2`,   I get the error:

```
zsh: command not found: puts
```

I'm not sure how to solve it. Any ideas much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are entering Ruby code in the shell.

Try executing `irb` to start an interactive Ruby shell.  Alternatively, if you have already created a rails project (`rails new <projectname>`) you could go into that directory and type `rails c` or `rails console`.

Comment: We all have to start somewhere. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
puts 1+2
```

is a Ruby statement. To execute it, you can use the commands `irb` (interactive Ruby) or `ruby` (the Ruby interpreter):

```
irb
```

and when you're in, you can execute:

```
puts 1+2
```

Or,

```
ruby -e "puts 1+2"
```